# How to deal with slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to reproduce the results of the paper "Boosting the Speed of Entity Alignment10×: Dual AttentionMatching Network with Normalized Hard Sample Mining"(`https://github.com/MaoXinn/Dual-AMN`)。
It uses  "Python = 3.6 Keras = 2.2.5  Tensorflow = 1.14.0  jupyter Scipy Numpy tqdm numba"。
And now it's not easy to get such version of tf. So I use tensorflow>=2.2 and "import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf    tf.disable_v2_behavior()"
and then something wrong happened.

Here is the code

```python
train_model.compile(loss=lambda y_true,y_pred: y_pred,optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr))
```

and the information is

```
"ValueError: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice\[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1\](loss/lambda_2_loss/Shape, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack_1, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: \[0\], \[1\], \[1\], \[1\] and with computed input tensors: input\[1\] = \<-1\>, input\[2\] = \<0\>, input\[3\] = \<1\>."
```

the whole information is

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in \_create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
1811   try:
\-\> 1812     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
1813   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice\[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1\](loss/lambda_2_loss/Shape, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack_1, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: \[0\], \[1\], \[1\], \[1\] and with computed input tensors: input\[1\] = \<-1\>, input\[2\] = \<0\>, input\[3\] = \<1\>.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-5-57acd3fea879\> in \<module\>
\----\> 1 model,get_emb = get_trgat(dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
2                           node_size=node_size,
3                           rel_size=rel_size,
4                           depth=depth,
5                           gamma =gamma,

\<ipython-input-4-e9d7ed4a9577\> in get_trgat(node_hidden, rel_hidden, triple_size, node_size, rel_size, dropout_rate, gamma, lr, depth)
95     inputs = \[adj_input,index_input,val_input,rel_adj,ent_adj\]
96     train_model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs + \[alignment_input\],outputs = loss)
\---\> 97     train_model.compile(loss=lambda y_true,y_pred: y_pred,optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr))
98
99     feature_model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs,outputs = out_feature)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in \_method_wrapper(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
455     self.\_self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
456     try:
\--\> 457       result = method(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
458     finally:
459       self.\_self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, distribute, \*\*kwargs)
456
457       # Creates the model loss and weighted metrics sub-graphs.
\--\> 458       self.\_compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics()
459
460       # Functions for train, test and predict will

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in \_method_wrapper(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
455     self.\_self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
456     try:
\--\> 457       result = method(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
458     finally:
459       self.\_self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py in \_compile_weights_loss_and_weighted_metrics(self, sample_weights)
1539       #                   loss_weight_2 \* output_2_loss_fn(...) +
1540       #                   layer losses.
\-\> 1541       self.total_loss = self.\_prepare_total_loss(masks)
1542
1543   def \_prepare_skip_target_masks(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py in \_prepare_total_loss(self, masks)
1599
1600           if hasattr(loss_fn, 'reduction'):
\-\> 1601             per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(y_true, y_pred)
1602             weighted_losses = losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
1603                 per_sample_losses,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py in call(self, y_true, y_pred)
248     """
249     if tensor_util.is_tensor(y_pred) and tensor_util.is_tensor(y_true):
\--\> 250       y_pred, y_true = tf_losses_util.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
251           y_pred, y_true)
252     ag_fn = autograph.tf_convert(self.fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx())

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/util.py in squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(y_pred, y_true, sample_weight)
76       squeeze_dims = lambda: confusion_matrix.remove_squeezable_dimensions(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
77           y_true, y_pred)
\---\> 78       is_last_dim_1 = math_ops.equal(1, array_ops.shape(y_pred)\[-1\])
79       maybe_squeeze_dims = lambda: control_flow_ops.cond(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
80           is_last_dim_1, squeeze_dims, lambda: (y_true, y_pred))

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
200     try:
\--\> 201       return target(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in \_slice_helper(tensor, slice_spec, var)
1011       var_empty = constant(\[\], dtype=dtypes.int32)
1012       packed_begin = packed_end = packed_strides = var_empty
\-\> 1013     return strided_slice(
1014         tensor,
1015         packed_begin,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
200     try:
\--\> 201       return target(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in strided_slice(input\_, begin, end, strides, begin_mask, end_mask, ellipsis_mask, new_axis_mask, shrink_axis_mask, var, name)
1184     strides = ones_like(begin)
1185
\-\> 1186   op = gen_array_ops.strided_slice(
1187       input=input\_,
1188       begin=begin,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in strided_slice(input, begin, end, strides, begin_mask, end_mask, ellipsis_mask, new_axis_mask, shrink_axis_mask, name)
10345     shrink_axis_mask = 0
10346   shrink_axis_mask = \_execute.make_int(shrink_axis_mask, "shrink_axis_mask")

> 10347   \_, \_, \_op, \_outputs = \_op_def_library.\_apply_op_helper(
> 10348         "StridedSlice", input=input, begin=begin, end=end, strides=strides,
> 10349                         begin_mask=begin_mask, end_mask=end_mask,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in \_apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, \*\*keywords)
740       # Add Op to graph
741       # pylint: disable=protected-access
\--\> 742       op = g.\_create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
743                                  name=scope, input_types=input_types,
744                                  attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in \_create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
3475     # Session.run call cannot occur between creating and mutating the op.
3476     with self.\_mutation_lock():
\-\> 3477       ret = Operation(
3478           node_def,
3479           self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
1972       if op_def is None:
1973         op_def = self.\_graph.\_get_op_def(node_def.op)
\-\> 1974       self.\_c_op = \_create_c_op(self.\_graph, node_def, inputs,
1975                                 control_input_ops, op_def)
1976       name = compat.as_str(node_def.name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in \_create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
1813   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
1814     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
\-\> 1815     raise ValueError(str(e))
1816
1817   return c_op

ValueError: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice\[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1\](loss/lambda_2_loss/Shape, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack_1, loss/lambda_2_loss/strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: \[0\], \[1\], \[1\], \[1\] and with computed input tensors: input\[1\] = \<-1\>, input\[2\] = \<0\>, input\[3\] = \<1\>.

>
```

`I've tried to change the version of numba/ change the package like tf.keras.optimizer.adam/logicy.RMSprom...`

Comment: What is your goal with this loss function?

Answer (score 0):

The mismatch in dimensions used in the loss computation may be the cause of the error you're experiencing. It appears that there is a problem with the *lambda y_true*, *y_pred*:  y_pred function you gave as the loss function, particularly with the slicing operation.

I have some ideas to troubleshoot and possibly resolve the problem:

- **Examine the y_true and y_pred's shapes**: Verify that y_true and y_pred have the expected shapes by printing their shapes in the loss function. This is how you can change the loss function:

  train_model.compile(loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: print(tf.shape(y_true), tf.shape(y_pred)) or y_pred, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr))
- **Adjust the Loss Function:** If the problem continues, consider substituting the lambda function with a more conventional loss function. The mean squared error (MSE), for instance, or another suitable loss given your task can be used.

  train_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr))

I hope that these suggestions can assisst you to handle with the issue!